# Map XML to SQL for easy export

Tags: python, mysql, sql, xml

I have the following XML which I want to map to relational model, so that I can query and re-export the same XML again.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<document name="001_COUNTERPARTY_CATEGORY_UK_BOE" date="2022-06-30" level="01-01-xx-xx-xx">

<PARTY F="01-01" PARTY_ID="201_A_Prod_P" />
<PARTY_FIELD F1="01-01" PARTY_ID="201_A_Prod_P" fieldname="CTY0" value="IR"/>
<PARTY_FIELD F1="01-01" PARTY_ID="201_A_Prod_P" fieldname="CTY1" value="IR"/>
<PARTY_FIELD F1="01-01" PARTY_ID="201_A_Prod_P" fieldname="SIE" value="64_19"/>
<PARTY_FIELD F1="01-01" PARTY_ID="201_A_Prod_P" fieldname="SIE" value="0"/>

<CHANNEL F="01-01" CHANNEL_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT"/>
<CHANNEL_FIELD F="01-01" CHANNEL_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="PRD013" value="1010"/>
<CHANNEL_FIELD F="01-01" CHANNEL_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="CUR007" value="GBP"/>
<CHANNEL_FIELD F="01-01" CHANNEL_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="PARTY_ID30" value="201_A_Prod_P"/>

<RATE F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT"/>
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="CHANNEL_ID0" value="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT"/>
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="C213" value="100000"/>    
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="C214" value="100000"/>    
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="C215" value="100000"/>    
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="PTY001" value="1"/>
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="PTY002" value="1"/>
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="PTY006" value="0"/>
<RATE_FIELD F="01-01" RATE_ID="201_A_Prod_PRODUCT" fieldname="PTY025" value="0"/>

</document>
```

`PARTY` AND `CHANNEL` relate to each other by `CHANNEL_FIELD's` attribute  `PARTY_ID30`

and `CHANNEL` relate with `RATE` by `RATE_FIELD's` attribute `CHANNEL_ID0`

I created tables as following, but I am not able to query them to export like the xml given:

```
PARTY (F,PARTY_ID,PARTY_FIELDNAME,PARTY_FIELDVALUE)
CHANNEL (F,CHANNEL_ID,CHANNEL_FIELDNAME,CHANNEL_FIELDVALUE)
PRODUCT (F,RATE_ID,RATE_FIELDNAME,RATE_FIELDVALUE)
```

Either I need to change the schema to let me query and export rows to create this xml or build query to generate rows in same order as xml from above schema.

An alternate approach is to export rows in csv and then use python to generate xml, but it would be overhead for large dataset

Comment: Check if this helps in anyway: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/xml-functions.html

Comment: The data model with one particular `CHANNEL_FIELD` `fieldname` being a foreign key is a bit messed up. Are you sure you want to stick with this model? This is really weird, even for XML.

Comment: @digitalarbeiter I understand, but out source system generating data as this

Comment: Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html

Answer (score 0):

I would split this up in `parties`/`party_fields` tables (same for channels and rates):

```
CREATE TABLE parties (id VARCHAR(32), f TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE party_fields (party_id VARCHAR(32), f TEXT, fieldname TEXT, value TEXT, FOREIGN KEY(party_id) REFERENCES parties(id));
```

(Side note: from your example data it seems you can't even have a UNIQUE constraint on `(party_id, fieldname)` as the fieldname "SIE" occurcs twice.)

Then use Python's `xml.etree.ElementTree` to iterate over the XML document and generate `INSERT` statements depending on the elements `tag` (I'm glossing over the MySQL client code a bit, assuming you have a `cursor`):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
for node in et.fromstring(the_long_xml_string):
    if node.tag == "PARTY":
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO parties (id, f) VALUES (%s, %s)",
            (node.attrib["PARTY_ID"], node.attrib["F"]),
        )
    elif node.tag == "PARTYFIELD":
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO party_fields (party_id, f, fieldname, value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (node.attrib["PARTY_ID"], node.attrib["F"], node.attrib["fieldname"], node.attrib["value"]),
        )
    elif node.tag == "CHANNEL":
        ...
cursor.commit()
```

Frankly with this XML structure, I wouldn't bother with the foreign keys in party fields with fieldname `PARTY_ID30` - I think that would really mess up your database schema (well, at least I can't think of a way to do this cleanly; maybe someone else can).

Now to (re-)generate XML, you can iterate over the parties from the database:

```
current_party_id = None
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM party_fields ORDER BY party_id ASC"):
    if row["party_id"] != current_party_id:
        out.write(f'<PARTY PARTY_ID="{row["party_id"]}" F="{row["f"]} />\n"')
        current_party_id = row["party_id"]
    out.write(f'<PARTY_FIELD PARTY_ID="{row["party_id"]}" F="{row["f"]}" fieldname="{row["fieldname"]}" value="{row["value"]}" />\n')
```

... and the same for channels and rates.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Not sure if I'm a "reputable source," though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯